# Read ESRI Shapefile in Java (.dbf) using geoTools

Tags: java, geotools

im trying to get the attribute table from esri shapefiles in java but i only managed to get the header table using Geotools library ?
Here is my source code :

```
        File dbfFile = new File("C:/Users/ilyasse2.0/Desktop/shapefiles/marocShp/mar_admbndp_admALL_unhcr_itos_20201203.dbf");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbfFile);
        DbaseFileReader dbfReader = new DbaseFileReader(fis.getChannel(), false, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        DbaseFileHeader dbfHeader = dbfReader.getHeader();
        System.out.println(dbfHeader.getRecordLength());
        List<String> names = new Vector<String>();
        int n = dbfHeader.getNumFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) names.add(dbfHeader.getFieldName(i));
        System.out.println(names);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `ShapefileDataStore` to read a Shapefile, you can then iterate through the features and extract the attributes. Note: the file should end in `.shp`, GeoTools will find the other necessary files.

```
List attributes = new ArrayList<>();
FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource();        
FeatureType schema = source.getSchema();

try(SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures();SimpleFeatureIterator iterator =  featureCollection.features()) {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // copy the contents of each feature and transform the geometry
        SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
        attributes.add(feature.getAttributes());
     }

 }
```

Comment: So basicly i dont need to get each file separately  and look for the infos ? The shapefile (.shp) is enough to do that?

Comment: The datastore looks at all of the files so you need them all, but you only need to refer to the .shp file